# Mapping data from contentful

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby, contentful

I've been following a tutorial series and I'm trying to extrapolate on what I've done thus far.

I have queried contentful to return the product details for which one of the data types is an array of productFeatures. I've tried to map this to a list and was expecting this to iterate out several li's. However, I've ended up with one li that contains all of the entries. Can anyone help me understand what I've misunderstood here?

This is my attempt in the product features component

```
import React from 'react'
import { Tab, Tabs, TabList, TabPanel } from 'react-tabs';
import './spec.css'

const Spec = ({data}) =>(

    <div>
        <Tabs>
            <TabList>
            <Tab>Key Features</Tab>
            <Tab>Product Documents</Tab>
            </TabList>

            <TabPanel>
                <ul className="spec_list">
                    {data.allContentfulProductPage.edges.map(edge =>(
                        <li className="spec_list__item">{edge.node.productFeatures}</li>
                    ))}

                </ul>
            </TabPanel>
            <TabPanel>
            <h2>Any content 2</h2>
            </TabPanel>
        </Tabs>
    </div>
)

export default Spec
```

---

Here is the graphql query return

```
{
  "data": {
    "allContentfulProductPage": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "productTitle": "HD Pro Projector M220",
            "productPrice": 299,
            "productDescription": {
              "productDescription": "Designed for use with iPhone*, iPad*, MacBook, and Apple TV, the Miroir HD Projector M220 delivers HD-quality projection for streaming, entertainment, or presentation purposes. Even better, it's small enough to fit in your briefcase or bag. The projector uses a long-lasting LED light source and is built with Texas Instrument's DLP technology, which provides a cinema-quality movie experience.\n"
            },
            "productFeatures": [
              "Texas Instruments DLP Technology",
              "1280 x 720 (720p) native resolution",
              "1080p maximum input resolution",
              "Auto focus with vertical keystone",
              "HDMI input",
              "Viewable screen size from 20 to 100 inches",
              "Built-in lithium-ion battery",
              "Two hours of projecting time",
              "Two built-in 2-watt speakers; audio out jack (3.5mm)"
            ],
            "productImage": [
              {
                "file": {
                  "url": "//images.ctfassets.net/2nhrtgh52wv0/7u8biIRohlsl0OFKBWZ0ti/1dabcec4edd13dee708107929ec8e505/product-shot.jpg"
                }
              },
              {
                "file": {
                  "url": "//images.ctfassets.net/2nhrtgh52wv0/7u8biIRohlsl0OFKBWZ0ti/1dabcec4edd13dee708107929ec8e505/product-shot.jpg"
                }
              }
            ],
            "productSceneImage": {
              "file": {
                "url": "//images.ctfassets.net/2nhrtgh52wv0/6AzIFw9pZDsRtH1JI3A9XR/80ca785ffc60310690e337f7f936a74f/front-room-scene.jpg"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the graphql query return

```
export const query = graphql`
  query ProductQuery {
    allContentfulProductPage{
      edges{
        node{
          productTitle
          productPrice
          productFeatures
          productDescription {
            productDescription
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code. Since `edges` is an array and you're trying to access the first element to access `productFeatures`, you need to add `edge[0]`.

```
<ul className="spec_list">
                {data.allContentfulProductPage.edges[0].node.productFeatures.map(feature =>(
                    <li className="spec_list__item">{feature}</li>
                ))}
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. That has yielded "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"

Comment: Can you show the code where you're storing the graph query return data?

Comment: Added it to the above

Comment: That's worked! Thank you very much mate, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I have one question for you do you need the list contains this value
              "Texas Instruments DLP Technology",
              "1280 x 720 (720p) native resolution",
              "1080p maximum input resolution",
              "Auto focus with vertical keystone",
              "HDMI input",
              "Viewable screen size from 20 to 100 inches",
              "Built-in lithium-ion battery",
              "Two hours of projecting time",
              "Two built-in 2-watt speakers; audio out jack (3.5mm)"
if is that true

```
<ul className="spec_list">
                    {data.allContentfulProductPage.edges.productFeatures.map(edge =>(
                        <li className="spec_list__item">{edge }</li>
                    ))}

                </ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've tried that and now I'm getting the error

Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: data.allContentfulProductPage.edges.map(elem=>elem.node.productFeatures)

Comment: <ul className="spec_list">
                    {data.allContentfulProductPage.edges.map(elem=> 
                        <li className="spec_list__item">{elem.node.productFeatures }</li>
                    ))}

                </ul>

Comment: That has yielded the same result as the original attempt

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data1={
  "data": {
    "allContentfulProductPage": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "productTitle": "HD Pro Projector M220",
            "productPrice": 299,
            "productDescription": {
              "productDescription": "Designed for use with iPhone*, iPad*, MacBook, and Apple TV, the Miroir HD Projector M220 delivers HD-quality projection for streaming, entertainment, or presentation purposes. Even better, it's small enough to fit in your briefcase or bag. The projector uses a long-lasting LED light source and is built with Texas Instrument's DLP technology, which provides a cinema-quality movie experience.\n"
            },
            "productFeatures": [
              "Texas Instruments DLP Technology",
              "1280 x 720 (720p) native resolution",
              "1080p maximum input resolution",
              "Auto focus with vertical keystone",
              "HDMI input",
              "Viewable screen size from 20 to 100 inches",
              "Built-in lithium-ion battery",
              "Two hours of projecting time",
              "Two built-in 2-watt speakers; audio out jack (3.5mm)"
            ],
            "productImage": [
              {
                "file": {
                  "url": "//images.ctfassets.net/2nhrtgh52wv0/7u8biIRohlsl0OFKBWZ0ti/1dabcec4edd13dee708107929ec8e505/product-shot.jpg"
                }
              },
              {
                "file": {
                  "url": "//images.ctfassets.net/2nhrtgh52wv0/7u8biIRohlsl0OFKBWZ0ti/1dabcec4edd13dee708107929ec8e505/product-shot.jpg"
                }
              }
            ],
            "productSceneImage": {
              "file": {
                "url": "//images.ctfassets.net/2nhrtgh52wv0/6AzIFw9pZDsRtH1JI3A9XR/80ca785ffc60310690e337f7f936a74f/front-room-scene.jpg"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
 console.log(data1.data.allContentfulProductPage.edges.map(elem=>elem.node.productFeatures))
```

it works for javascript are you sure it is not working correctly

Comment: So I am getting all of the result back, but not in their own <li>, the are all in one <li>

<li class="spec_list__item">
<!-- react-text: 57 -->Texas Instruments DLP Technology<!-- /react-text -->
<!-- react-text: 58 -->1280 x 720 (720p) native resolution<!-- /react-text -->
<!-- react-text: 59 -->1080p maximum input resolution<!-- /react-text -->
</li>

Comment: Just look about for where I might do that?

Comment: just click on beside  the answer form in the above triangle